# angular 2 , how to refresh table data after delete element from this table

Tags: angular

1 .list-of-links.component.html

```
<table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
          №
          </th>
          <th>
           Logo
          </th>
          <th style="text-align: center">
            Link
          </th>
          <th>
            Action
          </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="active"  *ngFor="let link of list ; let i=index">
          <td>
            {{i+1}}
          </td>
          <td>
            <img *ngIf="link.domain ==='rutracker.org'" src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/S0dUXg8MuXp4_AUaIvmO5c-qJ5bH_vKtpdI5B7gHhiTAJF-t-UJYR9uuAPF7qN4fUA=w300" height="30" width="30">
          </td>
          <td style="text-align: center">
            <a href="{{link.torrentLink}}" >{{link._linkID.linkTitle}}</a>
          </td>
          <td>
            <button (click)="onSubmitForDelete(this.list[i]._linkID._id)" >delete</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

2. component for this html

```
 private list ;

      constructor(private listOfLinks : ListOfLinks) {

      }

      async ngOnInit() {
        this.list = await this.listOfLinks.getLinksList();
      }

      async onSubmitForDelete (data){
         try{
           this.listOfLinks.deleteLink(data);
         }catch(err){
           return err;
         }
      }
```

3. service function

> ```
>  deleteLink (_linkID){
>     return this.http.get('/api/delete/'+_linkID).toPromise()
>   }
> ```

As you can see in my component above, I have some list of data .. I can delete data from this list ( I have some service which do it ). But I can't understand how can I refresh my table after deleting any component from this list

Comment: Either remove deleted row from `this.list` or call `getLinksList()` again.

Comment: async onSubmitForDelete (data){
     try{
       await this.listOfLinks.deleteLink(data);
       this.list = await this.listOfLinks.getLinksList();
     }catch(err){
       return err;
     }
  }

You helped me ) Thanks for it ))

Answer (score 1):

```
async onSubmitForDelete (data){
try{ 
   await this.listOfLinks.deleteLink(data); 
   this.list = await this.listOfLinks.getLinksList();
}catch(err){
   return err; 
} }
```

-->> hope it will help someone )Thanks for helping "kemsky" and "Dennis"

Answer (score 0):

```
async onSubmitForDelete (data){
     try{
       this.listOfLinks.deleteLink(data).then(() => {
           // Find index of "data" in your "list" and delete that element from your list yourself
           // OR
           // request the whole list again from your service and populate "list" again
       };
     }catch(err){
       return err;
     }
  }
```